# DataTemplate equivalent in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Looking for the WPF equivalent of the following:

```
<controls:TabItem
    Foreground="Black"
    Header="{Binding Path=Home.Header}"
    Content="{Binding **Path=Home**, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Home is:

```
public ViewModelBase Home
{
    get
    {
        return this._homeViewModel;
    }
}
```

Inside my `ViewModel`, I am unable to bind the XAML to the `_homeViewModel` in Silverlight.

Any ideas ?

Comment: As a side note, setting Mode=OneWay on a binding is always pointless in a Silverlight project. Silverlight doesn't support setting a different default binding mode on a DependencyProperty so everything is OneWay by default. Pretty nasty on stuff like TextBox.Text and ListBox.SelectedItem (Silverlight can be *really* frustrating for WPF developers)

Comment: @Alun, I am a WPF, I recently decided to abandon WPF for the [lack of the support of RIA Services](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621763/support-wcf-ria-service-and-mvvm-generators-for-wpf-projects-add-project-templates-for-it "Support WCF RIA Service in WPF projects..."), now I find myself addicted to RIA and in the other hand I am so frustrated from the [lack of basic functionality as `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1632123-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged) and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight still doesn't support implicit DataTemplates :-(

The best you can do is to use an attached behaviour to set the DataTemplate yourself (and have the behaviour get a DataTemplate with a key that is defined by convention).

Google "Attached Behaviour" if that was gobbledygook.